# Angular - "has no exported member 'Observable'"

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular6, rxjs6

[image: code]

[image: error info]

**Typescript code:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';
import { Hero } from './hero';
import { HEROES } from './mock-heroes';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class HeroService {

  constructor() { }

  getHeroes(): Observable<Hero[]> {
    return of(HEROES);
  }

}
```

**error info:**

> error TS2307: Cannot find module 'rxjs-compat/Observable'.
>   node_modules/rxjs/observable/of.d.ts(1,15): error TS2307: Cannot find
>   module 'rxjs-compat/observable/of'. src/app/hero.service.ts(2,10):
>   error TS2305: Module
>   '"F:/angular-tour-of-heroes/node_modules/rxjs/Observable"' has no
>   exported member 'Observable'. src/app/hero.service.ts(15,12): error
>   TS2304: Cannot find name 'of'.

**`package.json` file with Angular version:**

[image: version]

Comment: The framework you're using is named Angular. AngularJS is a different framework.

Comment: It seems you're using RxJS 6. The imports need to be changed when using that version (see the release notes). If you're not using Angular 6, then you should stick with RxJS 5.

Comment: thx.I'm using Angular6.0 ~

Comment: Here's the relevant documentation then: https://next.angular.io/guide/rx-library. Note that the imports are not the ones you're using.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

I replaced the original code with `import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs'`, and the problem is solved.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 226):

This might be helpful in **Angular 6**   for more info refer this [Document](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/observable.md)

1. **rxjs:** Creation methods, types, schedulers and utilities

```
import { Observable, Subject, asapScheduler, pipe, of, from, interval, merge, fromEvent } from 'rxjs';
```

2. **rxjs/operators**: All pipeable operators:

```
import { map, filter, scan } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

3. **rxjs/webSocket:** The web socket subject implementation

```
import { webSocket } from 'rxjs/webSocket';
```

4. **rxjs/ajax**: The Rx ajax implementation

```
import { ajax } from 'rxjs/ajax';
```

5. **rxjs/testing**: The testing utilities

```
import { TestScheduler } from 'rxjs/testing';
```

Comment: how can you 'work this out?' from first hand? searching SO works, but if the library was less well used.

Comment: npm install rxjs-compat --save

Answer (score 135):

Apparently (as you point in the error log), after updating to Angular 6.0.0 rxjs-compat is missing.

Run `npm install rxjs-compat --save` to install. Should fix it.

Comment: i'm also facing same issue, but what if i don't want to use backward compatibility package?

Comment: What if we don't want to use rxjs-compat?

Comment: This should be the correct answer.  It's not the right answer moving forward... but it's definitely the "right now" answer.

Answer (score 123):

Just put:

`import { Observable} from 'rxjs';`

Just like that. Nothing more or less.

Comment: Using 'rxjs' instead of 'rxjs/Observable' just solved my problem. I think, owner of the question should accept your answer.

Comment: This will definitely work. But does it also support Tree Shaking?

Answer (score 36):

You are using RxJS 6. Just replace

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';
```

by

```
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
```

Answer (score 36):

Try this:

```
npm install rxjs-compat --save
```

Answer (score 13):

What helped me is:

1. Get rid of all old import paths and replace them with new ones like this:

   `import { Observable ,  BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';)`
2. Delete `node_modules` folder
3. `npm cache verify`
4. `npm install`

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar issue.  Back-revving RXJS from 6.x to the latest 5.x release fixed it for Angular 5.2.x.

Open package.json.

Change `"rxjs": "^6.0.0",` to `"rxjs": "^5.5.10",`

run `npm update`

Comment: I think this is the best thing to do as rxjs 6 will be supported from Angular 6 only.

Answer (score 4):

Just remove `/Observable` from `'rxjs/Observable';`

If you then get `Cannot find module 'rxjs-compat/Observable'` just put below line to thr terminal and press enter.

```
npm install --save rxjs-compat
```

Answer (score 2):

My resolution was adding the following import:
`import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';`

So the overall code of hero.service.ts after the change is:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Hero } from './hero';
import { HEROES } from './mock-heroes';
import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class HeroService {

  constructor() { }

  getHeroes(): Observable<Hero[]> {
    return of(HEROES);
  }
}
```

Comment: Well that was the error he began with, the export is not there.

Answer (score 2):

The `angular-split` component is not supported in Angular 6, so to make it compatible with Angular 6 install following dependency in your application

To get this working until it's updated use:

```
"dependencies": {
"angular-split": "1.0.0-rc.3",
"rxjs": "^6.2.2",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.2.2",
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have not installed rxjs library please install

npm install rxjs-compat --save

Answer (score 0):

In my case this error was happening because I had an old version of ng cli in my computer.

The problem was solved after running:

`ng update`

`ng update @angular/cli`

Answer (score 0):

Update **angular-in-memory-web-api** version. The default **angular-in-memory-web-api** version installed during the tutorial **angular-tour-of-heroes** was 0.4. It worked like a charm in my case.
(Using Angular 7 with RxJS 6)

```
npm i angular-in-memory-web-api@0.8.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Run

npm i rxjs-compat

this works for me.