# When i'm doing ng serve this error shows

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, rxjs

Please, someone, guide me how to resolve this problem.!

```
Error Code:
Date: 2018-06-07T09:30:12.399Z
Hash: c8e1e30064a3aa0d6247
Time: 6037ms
chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 1.95 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.js, polyfills.js.map (polyfills) 693 bytes [initial] [rendered]
chunk {runtime} runtime.js, runtime.js.map (runtime) 5.4 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor.js, vendor.js.map (vendor) 325 kB [initial] [rendered]

ERROR in node_modules/rxjs/Observable.d.ts(1,15): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'rxjs-compat/Observable'.
src/app/authguard.guard.ts(3,10): error TS2305: Module '"C:/Users/HP/Desktop/AngularWithSession/mean-app/node_modules/rxjs/Observable"' has no exported member 'Observable'.

i ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49840152/i-get-an-error-when-learning-angular-has-no-exported-member-observable?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Import Observable from this package path:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
```

Comment: where should I add this path?

Comment: Search where you have used rxjs-compat/Observable and replace that with this.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using node version higher than 6.x.x. Try following code. It will fix the issue.

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using angular version 6 then You can use

// creation and utility methods

```
import { Observable, Subject, pipe } from 'rxjs';
```

// operators all come from rxjs/operators

```
import { map, takeUntil, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
```