# Angular 7 - getting error: 'rxjs has no exported member 'Observable'

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular7, rxjs6

This is my `package.json` file:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/material": "^7.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "~7.1.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "ng2-opd-popup": "^1.1.21",
    "rxjs": "~6.3.3",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
```

`service.ts` file code as below:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
//import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
//import   'rxjs/add/observable';
import { Observable} from 'rxjs';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class EmpService {
  employees=[];
  constructor(private _http: Http) { }
  addEmployee(info){
    return this._http.post("http://localhost/data/insert.php",info)
      .map(()=>"");
  }
}
```

I got the following error:

> rxjs has no exported member 'Observable'

Is there any kind of issues in versions?

Comment: have you tried run 'npm install' in cmd?

Comment: Yes,installed it before starting the project. node_modules files works well except this case

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I get an error when learning Angular."has no exported member 'Observable'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49840152/i-get-an-error-when-learning-angular-has-no-exported-member-observable)

Answer (score 5):

To be compliant with rxjs6 and angular 7, you have to replace:

```
import { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
```

by:

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
```

And import **Observable** like that:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
```

not like that:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
// or import   'rxjs/add/observable';
```

You may need to delete `node_modules` folder and launch `npm install`, because it seems you have some wrong packages in it.

Comment: Getting the same error . "(as no exported member 'Observable'.
node_modules/rxjs/Observable.d.ts(1,15): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'rxjs-compat/Observable'.)"

Comment: I think you have some wrong packages in `node_modules` folder. Just delete it and launch `npm install`

Comment: You import **Observable** like that `import { Observable } from 'rxjs';`, right ?

Answer (score 2):

Your code is written in old angular version. changes required are

```
1. Use of Http is deprecated
2. importing map & Observable


import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class EmpService {
  employees=[];
  constructor(private _http: HttpClient) { }
  addEmployee(info){
    return this._http.post("http://localhost/data/insert.php",info)
      .pipe(
        map(() => '' )
      )

  }
}
```

refer:

- [Angular IO](https://angular.io/api/common/http)
- [learnrxjs](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/map.html)

Comment: you have to import Observable from 'rxjs' in rxjs@6.3.3 like this: import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

Comment: Both works.. anyway we are importing a single class from rxjs

Comment: Both works but your import in rxjs@6.3.3 is really from 'rxjs-compat/Observable'. The good practice is don't import observable from rxjs-compat but use rxjs. The only good reason to use rxjs-compat is if you have dependencies that still rely on an older version of rxjs.

Comment: I read than all of deprecated things will be remove on version 7

Comment: DON'T `import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable'; ` USE    `import { Observable } from 'rxjs'; `

Answer (score 0):

Think your issue is related to wrong package, as the way you are doing it is right. 
The correct way to use `Observable` in  Angular 7 is by `import { Observable } from 'rxjs';`

Not sure if you upgraded from Angular 6, however, on the [upgrade docs](https://update.angular.io/):

> Switch from HttpModule and the Http service to HttpClientModule and
>   the HttpClient service. HttpClient simplifies the default ergonomics
>   (You don't need to map to json anymore) and now supports typed return
>   values and interceptors. Read more on angular.io
>
> Remove deprecated RxJS 6 features using rxjs-tslint auto update rules
>
> For most applications this will mean running the following two
>   commands:
>
> npm install -g rxjs-tslint rxjs-5-to-6-migrate -p
>   src/tsconfig.app.json
>
> Once you and all of your dependencies have updated to RxJS 6, remove
>   rxjs-compat.

After this has been resolved, run `npm install`

**Another possibility** is cached `node_modules` which can be removed :
`git rm -r --cached node_modules`
You may have some 
So, once this is cleaned, run an `npm install` and you should have the correct packages.