# Angular error TS2305: Module '"rxjs"' has no exported member 'tap'

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs-observables

I'm adding RxJS into Angular app. After installing RxJS, I got errors:
error TS2305: Module '"rxjs"' has no exported member 'tap'.

for the line of code:

```
import { catchError, tap } from "rxjs"
```

After running >npm start
I'm getting list of errors:
[image]

I tried to install RxJS below, it didn't help.

> npm install rxjs
> npm i rxjs-compat

Application located here:
[github.com/sam-klok/angular-kendo-grid-reactive](https://github.com/sam-klok/angular-kendo-grid-reactive)

PS Some people suggesting similarity with
[Angular - "has no exported member 'Observable'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49840152/angular-has-no-exported-member-observable)
I believe that it's overall useful article, however in my case library Observable working fine, and fixing methods described in it, didn't help to solve the issue.

Comment: from "rxjs/operators" instead of from "rxjs".

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Angular - "has no exported member 'Observable'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49840152/angular-has-no-exported-member-observable) Refer to Sanjeet's answer.

Comment: @yong-shun I saw that article, it's not the same issue. I tried rxjs/operators, same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked at the code of the application and see that it use Angular 12 and older version of RxJS (see screen of package.json below). And tap.ts file is "almost" empty, which tells me that something is with versions incompatibility. Currently I'm upgrading everything to Angular 13, and newer version of RxJS, will report later if it is a solution.

Basically solution was to upgrade version of Angular in this project.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try importing them from the operators. Those APIs were moved there a while ago even tho I do not know by heart now from what version on this applies:

```
import { catchError, tap } from "rxjs/operators";
```

Comment: I was unsuccessful with adding /operators. However upgrading Angular (including npm) helped.